# Add AskPath Dialog Installshield

Tags: installshield

How could I make prompt of the AskPath Dialog in my Installshield project ?

I explain :

When the user select Custom install, he could select the features and the destination path. But when he clicks the default install, it will install the progam to the default location. How could I make the 'Selection destination path' visible/prompt even the user select the default install ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to tweak the Next button control's event. Depending on various conditions, the next dialog is appropriately chosen. Modify the NewDialog control event to the argument "DestinationFolder", for the condition corresponding to "Default" install option.